# How to recover an inherited dormant account without paying a significant commission?

Tags: united-states, fraud, inheritance, dormant-account

I settled my parents' estate in 2012.  Now I am receiving records of a dormant account from Legal Claimant Services (Keane).  They claim to have found $68,000 in a dormant account.  I live in California, while my parents' estate was in Pennsylvania.  I cannot locate this account.  What choice do I have?  I'll have to pay a significant commission to recover my assets.

Can my broker or bank help me locate this account?

Comment: Note that this is an instance of "front some money in expectation of getting more", as are most scams.  If you've never heard of this entity before and they want their money before you receive yours, the chance of it being a scam becomes high.

Comment: Try the various information given by these answers and Googling/calling the State offices individually. Keane is a real company, but yes their fees can be stiff: http://www.nytimes.com/2013/06/22/your-money/seeking-owners-of-unclaimed-money-for-a-fee.html?_r=0

Answer (score 8):

Each state maintains a government office that handles lost bank accounts. You can work directly with them rather than going through any sort of broker or for-fee service, or paying any sort of commission.

The requirements for claiming the funds are usually documented on the state's websites these days. Basically you need to prove that the account holder is deceased and that you are a legitimate heir or executor, provide them with info about anyone else in the family who might be due a share of these funds, and swear to distribute the money reasonably among the survivors per the decedent's will.... all of which is a nuisance but protects the state and you from fraudulent claims